# What is an image in DSP context?

Tags: signal-analysis

I frequently see the term "image" thrown around in various DSP discussions.  What exactly does image mean in this context?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you asking this in the context of sampling and aliasing?

Comment: I believe so yep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of [sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem), an *image* is a copy of the spectrum of the original signal occurring at multiples of the sampling frequency. If the images overlap, then [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) occurs, i.e. frequency components above $f_s/2$ cannot be distinguished from components below $f_s/2$ (where $f_s$ is the sampling frequency), and the original signal cannot be completely recovered from its samples.

Comment: If I had a 44.1khz wave file, would the sampling frequency be 44.1khz?

Comment: yes, Alan.  a 44.1 kHz sound file has $f_s$ = 44.1 kHz.

Comment: I thought so, and this info helps, but I'm confused as to how if you overlap an image you get aliasing.  If the image is low frequency and it overlaps with itself, it seems like that would be just fine.  Also would it be accurate to say that an image is "one full spin of the oscillator"?

Comment: I'm also curious why the image has to occur at multiples of the sampling frequency.  Seems like if the image was 1/4 of the sampling frequency long that you could fit up to 4 of them in it without overlap

Comment: @AlanWolfe: Sampling creates shifted version of the original spectrum at integer multiples of the sampling frequency (see Sampling Theorem), that's just the way it is. This means that your sampling frequency must be greater than twice the maximum frequency in the signal in order for the images not to overlap. If they don't overlap you can reconstruct the original image by lowpass filtering, otherwise you can't.

Comment: I misunderstood and thought multiples of the sampling frequency essentially meant every 44.1k samples (for a 44.1hkz sound).  I get what you mean now, that the image has to start on an integer indexed sample essentially.  Thanks so much Matt, some of the other content on this site has been demystified a bit more now (:

Comment: @AlanWolfe: I'm still not sure if you understand me correctly. You have to look at the *frequency domain* of the signal. The original spectrum of the signal is centered around $f=0$Hz, and due to sampling, images of this spectrum are centered at $k\cdot f_s$, i.e. at integer multiples of the sampling frequency.

Comment: Ah... time to reread those links w/ this info in mind.  Thanks again Matt (: